# Julia on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, julia

I'm **Hadoop** engineer with primary interest in machine learning and data mining. With data locality utilization and modern tools like [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) (and especially [MLlib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html)) analysing terabytes of data becomes easy and pleasurable. So far I'm using Python API to Spark (PySpark) and am pretty satisfied with it.

However recently new strong player in scientific computations appeared - [**Julia**](http://julialang.org/). With its JIT compilation and built-in parallelism (among other things) it may become good competitor to traditional tools. So I'm interested, if I switch to Julia at some point, what are my options for using it on top of existing Hadoop stack? Are there any bindings or bridges allowing to run Julia scripts and still utilize HDFS's data locality?

**EDIT.** To make it clear: I'm not asking what tools are the best, not comparing Julia (or Hadoop) to other tools and not promoting any computational stack. My question is about projects that may help in **integrating two technologies**. No opinions, no long deliberation - just links to projects and short description.

Comment: For those voting to close: are there any reasons to consider this question opinion-based? I'm not asking what tool is the best, I'm asking what tools are available at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- [Elly.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Elly.jl) is a "Hadoop HDFS and Yarn client"
- the start of a Spark implementation: https://github.com/d9w/Spark.jl

edit: I should also point out the JavaCall package, which may allow utilization of existing Java libraries in this area. https://github.com/aviks/JavaCall.jl

(edit: originally linked to a now-deprecated HDFS binding project also by the Elly developer: https://github.com/tanmaykm/HDFS.jl)

Comment: The HDFS package is now being superceded by [Elly.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Elly.jl)

Comment: 1. I've also started my own wrapper for Apache Spark - [dfdx/Spark.jl](https://github.com/dfdx/Spark.jl). There's still a lot of work to do, but basic operations (including `map`, `reduce`, `text_file`, `collect`, etc.) are already in place. Moreover, issues and feature requests are highly welcome. 2. Another important project not mentioned here is [wildart/Mesos.jl](https://github.com/wildart/Mesos.jl).

Comment: wildart/Mesos.jl link is broken on github!